# Google-Maps Android: Issues drawing complex GeoJson polygons

Tags: android, google-maps, timezone, polygon, geojson

I have a webservice that returns GeoJson polygons (timezones) and I'm trying to draw them in a layer over the map object using `GeoJsonLayer`

I already tested the GeoJson file in [geojson.io](https://geojson.io/) and it looks fine (image at the bottom) but when I add it to the map its not being filled and some extra lines appear down south, it looks like its not closing the poly properly, this is the code I'm using to load the file (I have it locally in raw folder at the moment)

```
    val layer = GeoJsonLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.sample_timezones_response, requireContext())
    layer.addLayerToMap()

    val polygonStyle = GeoJsonPolygonStyle()
    polygonStyle.fillColor = resources.getColor(R.color.color_main_green_200, null)
    polygonStyle.zIndex = 10000f
    layer.features.forEach { it1 ->
        it1.polygonStyle = polygonStyle
    }
```

[This](https://api.jsonbin.io/b/621789b1ca70c44b6ea8b391) is the json file I'm trying with.

EDIT: the original json file was not followinf the right-hand rule, I fixed it with python lib: geojson-rewind, [this](https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6218f225c4790b340623da8e) is the fixed version that passes the test in https://geojsonlint.com/

I tried also updating to the latest version of the library ([18.0.2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer)) and updating the renderer to the newer one but it displays in the same way.

This is how it looks on android:
[image: android screenshot with defects]

[image: android screenshot with defects 2]

This is how its supose to look, same json file in geojson.io:
[image: displaying propertly on geojson.io]

Answer (score 0):

When validating the geojson, I get the error:

> Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6

> A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to the
> area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
> holes are clockwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, you where right in that regard, the data was not following the right-hand rule, I fixed it and now the json file passesd the test in geojsonlint but its still displaying wrong inside google maps, it also displays wrong in the iOS version of the app using g-maps as well, any other issues you could think of to have this fail? I fixed it with a python lib I found: geojson-rewind, and this is the new file produced that now passes the test: https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6218f225c4790b340623da8e

any other ideas as what could be wrong?

Comment: I would try clamping to the limits of the web mercator projection then, [-180, -85.06, 180, 85.06]. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280022/25837

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap map) {
        if (mMap != null) {
            return;
        }
        mMap = map;
        MarkerManager markerManager = new MarkerManager(mMap);
        GroundOverlayManager groundOverlayManager = new GroundOverlayManager(mMap);
        PolygonManager polygonManager = new PolygonManager(mMap);
        PolylineManager polylineManager = new PolylineManager(mMap);
// GeoJSON polygon
       try{
            GeoJsonLayer geoJsonPolygonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.your_file_name_here, this, markerManager, polygonManager, polylineManager, groundOverlayManager);
            // style your polygon here
            GeoJsonPolygonStyle geoJsonPolygonStyle = new GeoJsonPolygonStyle();
            geoJsonPolygonStyle.setFillColor(Color.RED);
            for (GeoJsonFeature f : geoJsonPolygonLayer.getFeatures()) {
                f.setPolygonStyle(geoJsonPolygonStyle);
            }
            geoJsonPolygonLayer.addLayerToMap();
            geoJsonPolygonLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener((GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener) feature ->
                    Toast.makeText(MultiLayerDemoActivity.this,
                    "GeoJSON polygon clicked: " + feature.getProperty("title"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeoJSON file could not be read");
        }
}
```